# Building .so module with autotools/libtool without .la and .a variants being installed

Tags: module, autotools, libtool

How to build and install a .so module with autotools/libtool without .la and .a libraries 
being also installed into --prefix path?

Currently i am using following Makefile.am:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libCurlDownloader.la
libCurlDownloader_la_SOURCES = Curl.cpp
libCurlDownloader_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version
```

It works, but in addition to libCurlDownloader.so it also installs libCurlDownloader.la and libCurlDownloader.a, what is undesirable.

**Update #1**

It is possible to make .a not be generated, by using either

```
./configure --disable-static
```

or

```
AC_ENABLE_SHARED(yes)
AC_ENABLE_STATIC(no)
```

in configure.ac

But it is still the question how to make .la not being installed into installation --prefix while having .so installed.

**Update #2**

It is possible to remove .la files from installation --prefix using

```
install-exec-hook: find $(DESTDIR)$(libdir) -type f -name \*.la -delete
```

Comment: You have a minor typo (should be install-exec-hook).

Comment: I think you can't, debian packagers are removing by hand la files in deb packages

Comment: That `install-exec-hook` seems like a bad idea. It would remove all .la files from the directory, not just the ones generated by your project. Not much of a problem if `DESTDIR` is used, but very wrong otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You should not necessarily delete the `.la` files. The `.la` files contains information that is used in two situations:

1. Statically linking against the built library. When statically linking (i.e., `.a` with `-static`), there is no information about the dependencies of the library being linked, so libtool can use the information in the `.la` file to create an appropriate `ld` command referencing all the necessary dependencies. This is often more important on an environment like MinGW where the linker requires the same library specified multiples in a particular order to resolve recursive dependencies. This is only a concern if one intends to build a static binary.
2. Dynamically loading the build library on *some* platforms (i.e., with `lt_dlopen` if using `libltdl`). Similarly, on certain platforms, dependencies of the compile module are not encoded in the binary, so the `.la` file is needed so that `lt_dlopen` will find and load the correct dependencies. On ELF platforms (including Linux) and PE platforms (i.e., Windows),  the dependencies are store in the library, so `lt_dlopen` will work without the `.la` files. The MachO format on MacOS can require `.la` files when building bundles.

The Debian/Ubuntu packagers have decided to exclude `.la` files from their packages because the second reason isn't appropriate on Linux and they would prefer you didn't build static binaries in the first place. On other platforms, which libtool is designed to support, the `.la` files may be needed for linking or running the program.

Comment: For static linking dependencies; there is almost always (even more often then existing .la files) `pkg-config` instructions are available.

Comment: Similary - even for dynamic linking `pkg-config` offers a better help then libtool crutches; in buildsystem-independent way.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question because it used the term "module", which in automake/libtool speak is the term for a plugin.  I have a plugin system in Finit, so I build my plugins with '-module' to avoid creating .a files. But I still get the .la files installed, which really is not even applicable in the '-module' case.

I've yet to find a documented way to skip .la files for plugins, but here is how I do it:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -shared
pkglib_LTLIBRARIES = alsa-utils.la bootmisc.la

install-exec-hook:
        @(cd $(DESTDIR)$(pkglibdir) && $(RM) $(pkglib_LTLIBRARIES))
```

To be clear, in my use-case there is nobody going to "link" against my plugin .so's, so the .la files really are of no use.

Comment: Have you found it? I really hate this.

Comment: @iharob nope, still using that hook rule to clean up the .la files. The project is [here](https://github.com/troglobit/finit) if you want to see more details.